# RSpec test for update within another action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am building an application in Rails 5 that sends user inputs back to a controller called "TestsController." If the params[:answer] matches the "correct_answer" in the controller action, the "test" object, which the TestsController controls, will have it's "score" increased by 1. If the answer does not match, the score is not increased.

Here is that action:

```
def question1 
    @test = Test.find(params[:id])
    correct_answer = "<p>"
    user_answer = params[:answer]
    if user_answer == correct_answer
        flash.now[:success] = "That is correct!"
        new_score = @test.score += 1
        @test.update(score: new_score)
    elsif params[:answer].present? && params[:answer] != correct_answer
        flash.now[:danger] = "Wrong answer." 
    end
end
```

Here is the RSpec test I attempted to write for this controller action:

```
describe 'GET #question1' do 

    it 'updates score if params match answer' do 
        get :question1, params: { id: test1.id, answer: '<p>'}
        expect(test1.score).to eq(1)
    end 

end
```

This test throws this error:

```
1) TestsController GET #question1 updates score if params match answer
 Failure/Error: new_score = @test.score += 1

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

I am unsure what I am doing wrong. It seems the @test object is not being assigned... although I wrote another test in this same RSpec file that says it IS being assigned. Plus this works in the app, just not in the test. Can someone help?

Comment: I would argue that `@test` is assigned, but `@test.score` return `nil`? Please ensure that `score` always returns a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it is telling you that `test.score` is **nil**.

You could solve it in two ways:

- When creating a test instace set its score to 0 with a before_create callback
- In the controller after `@test = Test.find(params[:id])`: `@test.score = 0 if @test.score.nil?`

PS: I would add a validation to ensure score is an integer

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

This is because the score is equal to `nil` in the `Test` object

You can create a new migration to ensure that on the database level, you'll always have a score which initially should be `0`

```
class ChangeTestsScoreNull < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column_null :tests, :score, 0
  end
end
```